# Kendo UI Web grid read fails after pagination

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo UI web Grid on ASP.NET MVC 4 Application.
I noticed a strange problem in it.

I have a grid with about 72 records, which will show only 20 records per page size.
you can click on pagination to see next 20 records.

after you click on next page 2 you can see next 20 records of 72.

Here I have a jQuery call to refresh grid.

```
var grid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.dataSource.read();
```

[image]

I noticed the problem is, when I use jQuery to read the grid again.
It is not resetting `[DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request` and that is creating the problem.

How can i fix this.

Solution
following @paris below code resolved the issue.

```
var grid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.page(1);
        grid.dataSource.read();
```

Comment: Are you trying to allow the user to stay on that page of the grid? I know that you can use `grid.dataSource.page(1);` to set the grid back to page 1 before the `read()` call. Also, while this is not directly related to your problem, you mention in your post that your grid "will show only 20 records per page". You can change the number of results displayed per grid page if you want more than 20.

Comment: Looks like this resolved the issue.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Please upvote my comment if it was useful (I'm still a baby SO user, I need rep dawg).

Comment: Well SO is not allowing me to up vote it, as I accidentally clicked it twice. Do you want to write your comment as answer, I can mark it my answer.

Comment: I appreciate that. Good luck with the rest of your code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting `grid.dataSource.page(1);` before the `read()` call if you don't mind refreshing the grid back to page one.

Comment: Good point!!!.. But I had a scenario where read() was not needed. The `page(1)` alone was sufficient.. Didn't do much analysis on that though